# Mongo DB - Update Document Field with GUID string using Mongosh

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

We are trying to update a field in one of the collection. the Field name is "id". We just need to generate a UUID string and assign it to all documents within the collection. We tried with `UUID()` which is generating a BSON Object. But when we try to use `toString()` function, it is getting converted to some random symbols. How can we generate a new UUID string from Mongo Shell and update the field in a document?

Answer (score 0):

`new UUID().hex()` returns the string without hyphens.

If you need the string with hyphens, you can use regex's match to slice and join.

```
const id = new UUID()
print(id.toString())
print(id.hex().match(/^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})$/).slice(1,6).join('-'))
```